# HttpTrigger parameter must be named "req"?

Tags: azure-functions

I generate a C# Azure Functions Visual Studio project using VS's template. The VS-generated Function method takes an `HttpRequest` parameter named `req` with an `[HttpTrigger]` attribute.

I make some minor changes to the VS-generated code for my coding preferences. I change the method's `[FunctionName]` to `example-func`. I change the name of the `req` parameter to `unused_req` to document that I'm not actually using that parameter in the method.

I build and publish the function app. I try to call my `example-func` Function from my browser. It should work, but I get get a 404, "the page you requested doesn't exist". I check my `example-func` Function in the Azure Portal. It exists in the Portal, and it's Enabled, and the portal's "Get Function URL" command shows the URL that I am in fact trying to call.

So, I start backing out my minor code changes, making my Function method code more like the original VS-generated code. When I change the name of my `unused_req` parameter back to `req`, it works; the Functions runtime can now find my function when I call it in my browser. I have since created more Function methods (by hand) and tested this. If the `[HttpTrigger]` param is named `req`, it works; if it's named something else, then the Functions runtime returns a 404.

Note, when the param is named `unused_req` (which causes a 404), the Function's function.json file (generated by the VS build), correctly contains a `"name": "unused_req"` property, i.e. the function.json correctly reflects my code and is correctly getting published to my Azure app.

Is this a bug in the Functions runtime? An "undocumented requirement", that the `[HttpTrigger]` param must be named `req`? With no specific error reported, just a general 404, it's very hard to diagnose when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

> When I change the name of my `unused_req` parameter back to `req`, it works; the Functions runtime can now find my function when I call it in my browser.

This works because **`HttpRequest`** class allows 3 object parameters `httpRequest`, `http` and `request` to be used in the Function Class declaration:

[image]

> I change the name of the `req` parameter to `unused_req` to document that I'm not actually using that parameter in the method.

Even if that renamed **`HttpRequest`** object is used or unused in the business code/logic, that will not work in the Function bindings.

[image]
[image]

If you use the above 3 parameters such as `httpRequest`, `http` and `request`for the HttpRequest class then function runtime will not give any error even these objects are not used in the business code/logic.

If you want the custom type to be declared in place of `HttpRequest`, it is possible as specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process,functionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#payload) on its declaration and usage.